# ng-pattern validation is not working in safari

Tags: javascript, html, validation, angularjs

I am using  `ng-pattern="/^(?=.*\d).{6,20}$/"`  for validating .

(Minimum 6 and maximum 20 characters. Must have at least one number)

It is working in other browsers except Safari .

I google it but no idea how to resolve this issue .

Please suggest .

Comment: I have faced the same issue.

Comment: @Jithu how did you solve this issue ?

Comment: I used jquery along with angular to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Because ng-pattern is just an Angular wrapper for HTML pattern which is not supported by Safari: [As explained in W3C schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp)